# Displaying information from CLIPS in a windows form

Tags: c#, clips

printout displays information in CLIPS.What do you do so as to display that information in a windows form.
For example when a rule is activated the display that is to be done on the RHS is done on the form instead

Answer (score 1):

Download CLIPSNET at http://www.clipsrules.net/CLIPSNET.html. The RouterFormsExample project demonstrates how to direct I/O to a Forms TextBox.